# Access async task handle from another async task

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm working on a piece of logic that spawns multiple async tasks, each of which loop indefinitely doing their thing. I want to implement a task that monitors these tasks. The approach I'm doing is the following: push the `JoinHandle` of each of the spawned tasks into a `HashMap` where the key is a certain unique string and the value is the `JoinHandle`. Then in a separate task I will loop and monitor these tasks, checking whether they are running by calling `is_finished()`.

The problem I'm facing is that I cannot pass the `HashMap` of handles to the task that will be checking their status without cloning it. And that is an issue, since (due to my limited knowledge) that will just spawn copies of these tasks under the hood, and essentially I won't have a reference to the original tasks.

I've decided to try using the `Arc` smart pointer, though I'm unsure if my approach is correct. Here's some code:

```
type TasksMap = HashMap<String, Arc<JoinHandle<()>>>;

pub async fn monitor_each(db: &DbClient) -> Result<()> {
    let orderbooks = db::get_orderbooks().await?;
    
    for (address, _) in orderbooks {
        // do some stuff

        let ob_monitor_task = orderbook.clone().monitor();
        
        // Add the OBs to a map of tasks, so we can monitor if they're running
        tasks
            .entry(orderbook.addr.to_string())
            .or_insert(ob_monitor_task);
    }
    Ok(())
}

/// Periodically check status of tasks
async fn check_tasks_status(tasks: &TasksMap) -> Result<()> {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            for (ob_address, task) in tasks.iter() {
                let og_task = Arc::get_mut(task).unwrap(); // getting compile Error here
                if og_task.is_finished() {
                    error!("Monitor task not running for OB with address {ob_address}");
                }
            }
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        }
    })
    .await?
}

impl Orderbook {
    /// Starts a task that monitors periodically the orderbook.
    pub fn monitor(&mut self) -> Arc<JoinHandle<()>> {
        let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
            loop {
                // do some stuff

                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5)).await;
            }
        });

        Arc::new(handle)
    }
}
```

So, I'm getting a compile-time error at `let og_task = Arc::get_mut(task).unwrap();`:

```
Note: expected mutable reference `&mut Arc<_>` found reference `&Arc<tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>>`
```

I've tried defining the `task` variable as `mut` in different ways, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what's going on.

And also, can I be sure that the `og_task` handle I get from the `Arc` will be the original one?

**Minimal reproducible example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5a9f0b40baa59ec3f8d3f752e842e79)**

Comment: *"that will just spawn copies of these tasks"* - no, `tokio::task::JoinHandle` does not implement `Clone`, so it will simply result in a compiler error.

Comment: Please provide a more complete [MRE]. While I can somewhat guess what you are trying to do, there are [many unrelated errors](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=932bdc47aa33d53cd9de2b6ebbbdcb00).

Comment: Why are you doing `Arc::get_mut` at all? `JoinHandle::is_finished` doesn't require a mutable reference.

Comment: *"The problem I'm facing is that I cannot pass the HashMap of handles to the task that will be checking their status without cloning it"* - Why so? Why aren't you just passing ownership?

Comment: This entire question screams [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me; I feel like solving this with `Arc` is the wrong approach.

Comment: I could easily solve with shared state in a DB or smth, but since I'm finding my way around Rust, I wanted to see if I can solve it only within the Rust runtime env.
So, I'm looking for suggestions on a better "the rust way" approach.

Comment: @Finomnis , I've provided a minimal reproducible example here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5a9f0b40baa59ec3f8d3f752e842e79

Comment: @Milkncookiez `check_tasks_status` isn't getting called anywhere. I suspect your real error is the way you call it, so please provide a proper [MRE] that actually uses the code somehow. Especially, I don't understand why the parameter of your `check_tasks_status` is a `tasks: &TasksMap` and not a `tasks: TaskMap`. An owned value would solve the entire problem you are having, and it seems confusing why you would pass a non-mutable reference here.

Comment: The reason I'm so insistent on this is because the error you are getting is actually a red herring and [easy to fix](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d1e1783f7ed1c1b13333110863f0987). Once fixed, though, the real problem starts to show: You can't move a `&Tasks` object into a `tokio::spawn`, because the spawned task might outlive the original object. There's no way of solving this easily. The easiest way is ownership, or another `Arc` around everything. But the amount of `Arc`s is getting rediculous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `Arc::clone(task)` first to get an “owned” value, which you can then mutate freely. Something like

```rust
            for (ob_address, task) in tasks.iter() {
                let mut task = Arc::clone(task);
                let og_task = Arc::get_mut(&mut task).unwrap();
                ...
            }
```

Comment: This will just fail at runtime due to multiple Arcs referencing the same value.

Comment: It shouldn't fail if there's only one task monitoring the others

Comment: @BallpointBen The act of `Arc::clone()` itself already makes sure that there are multiple `Arc`s.

Comment: `task` is a `&Arc`. `Arc::clone(task)` creates a second `Arc`, but the first still exists, so there are at least two, and `Arc::get_mut` will return `None`

Comment: Oh, whoops. Good points